# Getting user's country and keyboard language

Tags: c, cocoa, macos

In order to present the proper menu text and some other aspects of the UI I am trying to get the current user's country and keyboard language.
I know the locale (via the env. variable) but I can't find a way to get these two pieces of info.

The code is in C for Mac OS X. I can use Cocoa API to get them but they need to be called from C. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Automatic selection of language sucks! I hate it when google reverts to portuguese: my browser is setup to accept english with a very high priority, but Google insists on changing my preference to what it finds by matching my IP to country!!! Stupid Google! Sorry for the rant ... I suggest you let users define their interface in a configuration file

Comment: This isn't "automatic selection of language" - this is querying the system for what the user has actually chosen.

Comment: What if you go on vacation to France with your laptop? Then your settings are all for english, but the country is France (you want the notepad to "know" it's in France because of local news, local restaurants, local shops, ..., ...). Should the menus be presented in french?

Comment: @pmg please don't try to make this more complicated. It doesn't matter if I travel to japan or france. How do I get the language (as in English or French) and the country (as in France, Japan, United States, etc)

Comment: Maybe `/etc/timezone` has enough info for determining the country. On my system, its contents are `Europe/Lisbon`.

Comment: on a Mac? on Snow Leopard it doesn't exist

Comment: @Jessica: my bad! I though Mac's were UNIXes and didn't check thoroughly

Comment: @Edward - And using the default national settings is just terrible. Here we do everything in English, even though most of us don't have that setting. When I go to an MS support site, they translate the menus and headers to Swedish for me, even though the content is in English. Barf!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `CFLocaleCopyCurrent`, `CFLocaleGetValue` and `CFLocaleCopyPreferredLanguages` (note that the preferred language may not match the locale's language). See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFLocaleRef/Reference/reference.html).

Edit: ok, here's some sample code.

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    CFLocaleRef loc = CFLocaleCopyCurrent();
    CFStringRef countryCode = CFLocaleGetValue (loc, kCFLocaleCountryCode);
    CFStringRef countryName = CFLocaleCopyDisplayNameForPropertyValue (loc, kCFLocaleCountryCode, countryCode);
    CFShow(countryCode);
    CFShow(countryName);
    CFArrayRef langs = CFLocaleCopyPreferredLanguages();
    CFStringRef langCode = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex (langs, 0);
    CFStringRef langName = CFLocaleCopyDisplayNameForPropertyValue (loc, kCFLocaleLanguageCode, langCode);
    CFShow(langCode);
    CFShow(langName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I already have the locale. What I am searching id either the country (as in United States, France, etc) and language (as in English US, French, etc). Those APIs you mention seem to return locale IDs or an array with them

Comment: CFLocaleGetValue(locale, kCFLocaleCountryCode) gives you "US", "FR", etc; the items of the array returned by CFLocaleCopyPreferredLanguages are strings like "en", "fr". Use CFLocaleCopyDisplayNameForPropertyValue if you want a long name like "France" or "French".

Comment: I can't make it work on C. Any chance you can post a snippet? Thanks.

Comment: No, this is not an answer so far so please don't not accept this as the answer to the bounty

Comment: You should have mentioned what exactly went wrong when you tried coding it, but here's some sample code to get you started.